# Producing application/zip content using RESTeasy

Tags: rest, resteasy

This quesiton refers to the RESTeasy framework by jboss.

I'm using **the client framework** to call a third-party REST webservice. I was wondering if the RESTeasy framework has support to produce **application/zip** contents.

I've read the documentation, and I don't see any mention of that. Does RESTeasy provide the tools to handle a application/zip response (from a third-party Web service for example) ?

Can someone put me on the right direction ?

Comment: Based on your answer, it looks like you mean producing application/zip rather than consuming. Is that right? If so, can you fix it as it can easily confuse others looking for an answer to this. Overall your question seems a bit confused as you're talking about application/xml content under a header asking about application/zip.

Comment: It was an error, sorry for that, I fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This annotation did the trick for me :

```
@GET
@Produces("*/*")
@Path("/api/{language}.zip")
public File getSerieBaseInformation(@PathParam("language")String language);
```